# Move from BDE to ADO - Databse

Tags: delphi, ado, delphi-10.2-tokyo, bde

although the question might seem to be similar to other questions concerning this subject, I am afraid it is more complicated.
I try to run a program that I programmed a long time ago under win XP using Delphi 2005.
Now using Delphi 10.2.3 Toky, working with the same program, I get an error bdertl and intraweb 72 90 not found.
I simply deleted intraweb components.
When I also deleted bdertl the error remains.
In the program I use ADO compounds. I don't see any compound which might be from Paradox , BDE-
Can anyone help me to resolve the bdertl error?

Thanks

Thommy7571

Comment: Do you mean _Components_ instead of _compounds_?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you're getting after removing the components?

Comment: I'm not sure about Intraweb because I never use it but recent Delphi versions no longer install the BDE and related units by default. If necessary, you could delete your uses list and re-compile, then, reinstate to the uses list whatever units are needed to avoid "not found" errors from the compiler.

Comment: Hello Sami, yes sorry, off course...

Comment: hello Ken,   here it is [dcc32 Fataler Fehler] E2202 Package 'bdertl' wird benötigt, konnte aber nicht gefunden werden                                                             fatal error:  E2202 Package 'bdertl' is required, but could not be found               I got the same error as before deleting it from the run time library.  After deleting the intraweb component the error (which was also the same before) simply disappeared.

Comment: hello MartynA , yes I am also sure it is from the old version and I don't beleive that I used them. However I am not sure to know enough about the software to be sure but thanks for the suggestion. In another software I used database components (DBText) of BDE to display the data of the ADOTable. Does this belong to BDE? I don't know if I used that in this application but how is it possible else? Deleting DB Tables was no problem, but DB was a problem due to this I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

Check if BDE/Intraweb related pas files are present in the uses list. For example Dbtables, bde.

Comment: Hello Thanks very much, in a small unit that I had nearly forgotten (small and less significant) there was DB Tables in the USES List. BDE was not present anywhere..However, deleting DB Tables was not sufficient to eliminate the error. . I hope DB is OK.

Comment: Yes db is fine.. You can search if bdertl is present in required packages list in code.. Or check unit scope in project options